# How do I use reference links in a MVC RedirectToAction call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a basic table listing rows from a database, with edit links beside each one.  The table may be several pages long, so after the user edits a row, I want the user redirected back to the List view, and I want the page scrolled down to the row that was just edited.

In my controller, I have...

```
Return RedirectToAction("List")
```

Which redirects to ...\List

How do I make it redirect to ...\List#100

Comment: not the same issue but this could give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5568381/463785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the routing system, it is not possible to do that AFAIK. One way of doing it is to append the hash after the URL like below:

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("List", "Home") + "#poo");
```