# Redirect with both a Model and a fragment identifier

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using bootstrap with tabs and controlling navigation with a fragment identifier in the URL. This is my current usage from a Controller that is calling a view:

```
return RedirectResult(Url.Action("Dashboard", 
                                  new { id = account.Id }) + "#tab_NotesTab");
```

This works great, but now I need to pass the model from my action. Normally I pass it with the standard syntax:

```
return View(model);
```

How do I do both? I want to pass both a model and the fragment identifier to the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a solution for [TempData](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html)!

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  // var model = ...
  TempData["model"] = model;
  return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Dashboard", 
    new { id = account.Id }) + "#tab_NotesTab");      
}

public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
  var model = (MyModelType)TempData["model"];

  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I'm not following your example. The Dashboard view doesn't pass the fragment identifier, just the model.

Comment: BTW, I've tried your example to see if the fragment remained, but I ran into a problem that page didn't reload. I can step through the actions called and step through the cshtml view page, but when it is done processing the view, it the browser doesn't actually update.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue maybe.

Comment: I put a no cache attribute "[OutputCache(Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]" on both actions with no luck.

Comment: In your example, if I didn't have this no refresh issue, would the fragment "#tab_NotesTab" stay appended to the URL string when the Dashboard called the View? Basically it would be passed through?

Comment: The StackOverflow answer to [Including hash values in ASP.NET MVC URL routes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5568381/209259) seems to indicate that the hash should reach the client.  But realize that the hash is never sent to the server from browsers (the opposite direction).

Comment: Finally got it working, The hash does survive when the model is loaded.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return *new* RedirectResult(...`? As in `return new RedirectResult(...`, not `return RedirectResult(...`.