# WebApi Send String with # in it

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am sending a string to a Post method in WebApi.  The string contains a # character.  When the Post method receives it, the string is received without the # character and everything after it.

So if the string I send is

```
abc#def
```

The Post method actually receives

```
abc
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to use UTF_8 character set

Comment: Are you passing this parameter in the URI or in the request body?

Comment: From the Uri, public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] Foo model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this parameter is passed in the URI, anything after the `#` is ignored. This is standard web behaviour. You simply cannot do this sorry.

One thing you could do is take it in via the request body instead, that would work fine.

A similar question addresses the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567721/including-hash-values-in-asp-net-mvc-url-routes), although it's more to do with routing, but the same concept applies.